# Redirecting to Flask with NGINX

Tags: nginx, flask

I am new to Nginx. I want to create an auth server using Flask. My idea is to redirect users to my Flask port :5000 when they land on my homepage. After authentication, they will be redirected to the internal site (Another port)

I did the following

conf.d/default.conf

```
   server {

         listen 80;

         location / {

             root ..
             index ..
             proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;

         }

   }
```

and also tried the following

```
     server {

         listen 80;

         location / {

             root ..
             index ..
             proxy_pass http://localhost/auth;

         }

         location /auth {

              internal;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:<another port>;

        proxy_pass_request_body     off;

        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;



         }

   }
```

Comment: To redirect to port 5000 you can add:   `include proxy_params;   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;`  to your location config. I'm not completly sure if it'll work, but that's how I did it.